# O(mn) and O(mnlgn)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

for the above 2 big O's, what happens if n>>m . How does the big O change? Does it become O(n) in the first case. If yes ,why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you know about what the maximum value of `m` could be (depending on `n`).

If both `m` and `n` are independent variables `O(mn)` is `O(mn)` and cannot be further simplified. If you know that `m` will never be greater than `n`, but nothing else, you can also write it as `O(n^2)`. If you know for example that `m` will never be greater than `log n` (which would satisfy `n >> m`), `O(mn)` can be written as `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Programmer: The same thing except with `n log n` instead of `n`. I.e. if `m` is bounded by `n` you get `O(n * n log n)` and if `m` is bounded by `log n` you get `O(log n * n log n)`.

Comment: don't you think it will also converge to O(n) and why the term log n would be there.Please could you explain.

Comment: @Algorithmist: No, I don't. If `m` is bounded by `log n`, that means I can replace `m` with `log n` in the O-notation. It definitely does not mean that I can just remove it. I only could do that if `m` were bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

O(mnlgn) will always be greater than O(mn) regardless of the relative sizes of m and n. You would only remove terms or simplify if one of the terms is considered to be bounded or a fixed constant.  According to those statements, n and m are independent dimensions that jointly bound the runtime of an algorithm.  They both continue to matter in big-O notation unless one of them has a finite bound.  Even in that case, it may still be useful to leave in the bounded dimension m if comparing the runtime bounds of different algorithms that may vary in their complexity relative to m.

O(mnlgn) and O(mn) will not converge even if n >> m.  They will always be separated by a factor of m.  If m is variable and unbounded, then the rules of Big-O require that it stay.

Answer (score 0):

When n>>m O(mnlgn) would be greater than O(mn).Just solve by taking an example assume n=2^x.Yes when n>>m 
O(mn) would converge to O(n).

Comment: what would O(mnlgn) converge to? Also, I noticed that for small n , O(mnlgn) performs better than O(mn). WHy is that?

Comment: @programmer this happens because in Big O we do not take into consideration of the constant factors.This happens in case of insertion and merge sort.Where for small n insertion outbeats merge sort because merge sort has large constant factors.

Comment: how abt O(mnlogn)? what does it converge to

Comment: @programmer just take the case when n=2^20 and n>>m then O(mnlgn) would also converge to O(n).

Comment: This answer is misleading. `O(mn)` is only equal to `O(n)` if `m` is bounded by a constant.

Comment: @sepp2k @programmer has already stated that n>>>m thus we need to take this into consideration.

Comment: @Algorithmist: `n >> m` does not necessarily mean that `m` is constant. It could also be bounded by say `log n`, in which case it's not a constant factor (even though it's greatly less than `n`) and thus can not be removed.